# Prevent require.extensions being modified in node.js

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, iced-coffeescript

I am using IcedCoffeeScript. Some of my dependencies have a `coffee-script` dependency. When `coffee-script` is required it sets require.extensions['.coffee'] which overrides IcedCoffeeScript's extension.

This breaks my app.

I name all my files `.coffee`.

Is there a way to prevent `require.extensions['.coffee']` being changed once set?

Or is there another solution to my problem.

PS. I don't really want to rename all my iced files to `.iced`, although this would work.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed!

`main.coffee`

```
require 'iced-coffee-script'
Object.defineProperty require.extensions, '.coffee',  {writable: false}
```